# How can I upload profile picture in user extended model in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am not getting any error while uploading cover image to the Django's User extended model but I cannot see what is wrong I'm doing because it's not giving any error and not even updating my model. However I can change the bio by using this concept but i can't update the cover image to my User extended model.
Here I am giving the source code

**models.py**

```
class Memer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False, default="Hey! I'm new here.")
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover-images/%y/%m/%d/', default='cover-images/default/memerrank-bg.jpg', blank=False, null=False)
    profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-images/%y/%m/%d/', default='profile-images/default/memerrank-no-dp.jpg', blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UpdateCoverImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Memer
        fields = ['cover']
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user_ = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        memer = Memer.objects.filter(user=user_[0].id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Memer does not exist.")

    context = {
        'user_': user_,
        'memer': memer,
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        bioForm = EditBioForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.memer)
        coverImageForm = UpdateCoverImageForm(data=request.FILES, instance=request.user.memer)
        if bioForm.is_valid():
            memer_ = bioForm.save(commit=False)
            memer_.save()
            messages.success(request, "Bio successfully updated your profile")
            return redirect('/profile/'+user_[0].username)
        elif coverImageForm.is_valid():
            memer_ = coverImageForm.save(commit=False)
            memer_.save()
            messages.success(request, "Cover Image has been updated successfully!")
            # print(coverImageForm)
            return redirect('/profile/'+user_[0].username)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Something wrong happend")
            return redirect('/profile/'+user_[0].username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

**profile.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ UpdateCoverImageForm }}
 <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/ you are missing request.Files in your form

Comment: @iklinac could you please be more specify about what I should've to add into my code and why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: EditBioForm(data=request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.memer)

Comment: Anyway it's highly recommended that you will read that part of Django documentation

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev however I'm able to change the bio field of my user extended model but cover isn't getiing changed but when i try to change it from admin panel it changes. wait let me add my models to.

Comment: bc admin pages has their own "views" (deep inside Django library) AND those views pass `request.FILES` as needed

Comment: while your view doesn't pass that data

Comment: so if you want to make your view working as well - just pass more data

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev what are the more data's I have to pass? could you please tell me I prefer you watch again my models.py and views.py and please buddy help me with this I stucked on this since past three days.

Comment: First two positional arguments in the constructor of ModelForm are `data` and `files`. You should pass data to first one and files to second one. More information here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

Comment: If you don't have file fields here, then make no changes `bioForm = EditBioForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.memer)`

Comment: but here you should make the change `coverImageForm = UpdateCoverImageForm(data=request.FILES, instance=request.user.memer)` -> `coverImageForm = UpdateCoverImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.memer)`

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev Thanks a lot buddy now i get it I was passing request.FILES as a data but instead I have to pass request.FILES as files. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have gone through many possibilities and found the answer of this problem in which https://stackoverflow.com/users/764182/dmitry-belaventsev helped me.

So, the problem here is in `views.py`.

1.First two positional arguments in the constructor of ModelForm are data and files. You should pass `data` to first one and `files` to second one.

2.If you don't have file fields here, then make no changes

```
bioForm = EditBioForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.memer)
```

3.But here make the change

```
coverImageForm = UpdateCoverImageForm(data=request.FILES, instance=request.user.memer)
```

**to**

```
coverImageForm = UpdateCoverImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.memer)
```

And Boom your files will gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any errors simply because the code is doing exactly as you instructed it. The code will never enter into the elif statement, and this is because the "if bioForm.is_valid():" statement will always return True. I suggest you do something like this

```
if request.method == "POST":
        bioForm = EditBioForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.memer)
        coverImageForm = UpdateCoverImageForm(data=request.FILES, instance=request.user.memer)
        if bioForm.is_valid() and coverImageForm.is_valid():
            memer_ = bioForm.save(commit=False)
            memer_ = coverImageForm.save(commit=False)
            memer_.save()
            memer_.save()
            messages.success(request, "Profile successfully updated your profile")
            return redirect('/profile/'+user_[0].username)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Something wrong happend")
            return redirect('/profile/'+user_[0].username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

If you wish to update one field at a time then i suggest you make different views for each one of them.